# Android one shape resource file for different buttons

Tags: android

I've got a 5 buttons. They have a similar corners radius but different background color. Can i make one shape for radius and change buttons color with xml resources? So, main problem is set background color for them. I can't use `android:background` attribute twice. I thought about style, but in the syles i also need to set thia attribute twice. Is t possible to make only 1 shape file, or should create own file for each button?

Comment: you can set it from java code, set background for button in onCreate of the corresponding activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's what works:

shape.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#0f0"/>
</shape>
```

and in onCreate in your java code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

im Glad if i helped:)

Comment: selector worked only on button state, as i know. I dont think that it helps to set colors for defferent buttons.

Comment: yes, i created 5 shape files. Hope google will create some solution of this problem in next api.